# NgFor component doesnt update

Tags: angular, dom

I have a ng for loop with a component inside them. I am running a resizing function that sets the size of the component for each component. This all works great on load but on window resize the resizing function only fires for the last component in the list and not every component. Below is my parent for loop.

```
<masonry [options]="myOptions"> 
            <div masonry-brick class="masonry-item" *ngFor="let item of (feedsList$ | async);let i = index">
                 <grid-item [item]="item" [index]="i" [listLength]="(feedsList$ | async).length"></grid-item>
            </div>
        </masonry>
```

Below is the component resize function and the call.

```
 constructor() {
    window.onresize = (e) => {
        this.calculateItemSize()
    }

}

calculateItemSize() {
        const item = Math.ceil(this.index / 11);
        const groupIndex = 11 * item;
        let itemIndex = null
        if (groupIndex == 11) {
            itemIndex = this.index + 1
        } else {
            itemIndex = (this.index + 1) - (groupIndex - 11)
        }

        let dividedWidth = this.elemRef.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.clientWidth / 3
        let width, height

        switch (itemIndex) {
            case 2: {
                width = dividedWidth * 2 + 'px'
                height = dividedWidth * 2 + 'px'
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                width = dividedWidth * 2 + 'px'
                height = dividedWidth + 'px'
                break;
            }
            case 7: {
                width = dividedWidth * 2 + 'px'
                height = dividedWidth * 2 + 'px'
                break;
            }
            default: {
                width = dividedWidth + 'px'
                height = dividedWidth + 'px'
                break;
            }
        }


        this.renderer.setStyle(this.elemRef.nativeElement.parentElement, 'width', width)
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.elemRef.nativeElement.parentElement, 'height', height)
    }
```

Comment: Well I don't see any loop in your typescript, so it appears logical to me that it only applies to only one element.

Comment: in the parent template there is a ngFor bud =) look at the first code example

Comment: Let me repeat myself : **`I don't see any loop in your typescript`**. `ngFor` is for the template, not the typescript.

Comment: the second code snippet refers to the component and hte resize logic runs in there. so each component has that code and it runs the first time BUT not on window resize.

Comment: Well you should have stated that it was the code of a `grid-item`, I thought it was part of masonry ... Let me make an answer to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're redefining the listener of your window everytime you run this

```
window.onresize = (e) => {
    this.calculateItemSize()
}
```

This literally means

> bind this function to the variable `window.onresize`

So yeah, your last item is using it, and the others aren't.

The solution would be to move this code in the parent component, and use a `@ViewChildren` decorator to get all of your grid items, then run the function inside all of your children.

Comment: The problem is the index is in the child, I need that to set the styles. So if I move the on resize to the parent class, how can I recall the resize function in the child/griditem

Comment: As I told you, you must use a `@ViewChildren` decorator to get access to your children. Do you know what it is or not ?